# How can I query channel by checking if a field contains string on GetStream-IO

Tags: getstream-io

I would like to know how can I query fields on `GetStream.IO API` using something like `regex or contain syntax for matching strings`

#### Example

I would like to query channels that name contains `xyZ` not case sensitive, instead of equally matching the value, I've been trying to use the below, but no success

```
{ name: {$regex : ".*xyz.*"}}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: also have been looking for something like this.  My use case was to do a partial match on a channel name, i.e. channel name contains 'xyz'.  I find it strange that the queries do not support this.  Did you find any alternative other than select all then doing further filtering in code?

Answer (score 4):

Please note. The query syntax information is now available here:

- https://getstream.io/chat/docs/javascript/query_syntax_operators/

More info about running channel queries themselves:

- https://getstream.io/chat/docs/javascript/query_channels/

Answer (score 1):

Only a subset of mongo style queries are supported, as mentioned in https://getstream.io/chat/docs/#query_syntax , so your use case is not really supported with these kind of queries. It might be a solution for you to use custom data on your channel and query for the exact values. You can do that when you initialize (https://getstream.io/chat/docs/#initialize_channel) or update the channel.